# python detect image in a document

Tags: python, apache-tika

How can I detect images in a document say doc,xls,ppt or pdf ?

I came across with Apache Tika, I am trying command line option. http://tika.apache.org/1.2/gettingstarted.html

I am using Python2.7..

But not quite sure how it will detect images.

i am newbie to Django, Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Decide on a definitive list of file formats to support, then tackle each one individually. As a start, microsofts formats are all zip files. So those you can check if there is a non-empty image directory in the archive.

Comment: @kalhartt   : is there any other way then apache-tika to detect whether image is present in pdf or not (pure python)

Comment: [Python-tika](http://redmine.djity.net/projects/pythontika/wiki) might be of use to you, although the docs don't seem so complete. Without Tika [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old and I am reviving it because there are various solutions now to this problem.  Chris Mathamm, one of the developers of tika has made a python integration for tika that uses the JCC library's c++ bindings to access the jvm and run tika.  You can find that [here](https://github.com/cruns/python-tika-with-deps).

There is also a the [Apache Tika integration for Plone using portal transforms.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftw.tika/1.1.1)  Which uses the tika-jaxrs server to parse documents.